# Autoload Error: No such file or directory

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I have included autoload.php in the header of my site

```
include 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

From this i am receiving the following errors on my site:

> Warning: require_once(**DIR**/composer/autoload_real.php)
>   [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in
>   /homepages/6/d416629391/htdocs/leftovercheese/vendor/autoload.php on
>   line 5
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required '**DIR**/composer/autoload_real.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php5') in
>   /homepages/6/d416629391/htdocs/leftovercheese/vendor/autoload.php on
>   line 5

My code is:

```
// autoload.php generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer' . '/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit8be239f5caef32db03f87bb271ed6012::getLoader();
```

PHP Version: 5.2.17

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to load `vendor/autoload.php`, which will autoload that file for you:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

This is assuming that your file is located at the same directory level as the `vendor` directory.

Otherwise, adjust.

Comment: I have included the autoload.php file,

I think the original error message is a result of including the autoload.

Comment: The two files are located:

vendor\autoload.php

vendor\composer\autoload_real.php

Comment: The version of PHP i was using did not support __DIR__. Instead use __FILE__, as shown below.

> __DIR__  The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to
> dirname(__FILE__). This directory name does not have a trailing slash
> unless it is the root directory. (Added in PHP 5.3.0.)

Answer (score 11):

run `composer install`

That will import your packages and create the vendor folder as well as the autoload script. Also, make sure your relative path is correct.

Comment: running `composer update` helped me .

Answer (score 1):

For me, I updated some folder names and these updated are not reflected in `autoload_files.php` and `autoload_static.php`. I just had to run `php composer.phar dump-autoload`.